# Android emulator application load/start time

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I’m working with Eclipse and writing an Android application.  I’ve noticed that the load times to the Android emulator can vary significantly.  Recently, I found that manually going back to the main menu of the emulator helps my application load much faster.  This brings up two questions.

Is there a quicker way (read: automatic way) to exit out of my application rather than hitting the Back button multiple times until I get to the main app menu?

Secondly, is there something I am doing wrong that factors into the longer load time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not "the android way" but while debugging an app that was already using jni, I created a function that calls exit() and gave it a button.  This also helped as the eclipse install & launch mechanism was not entirely reliable at always running the new version - sometimes it was causing a resume of the old!